# Flutter How to use Times New Roman Font style in Text

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm need to implement Times New Roman Font in my flutter project. I tried google_font packege but in that i didn't find any font.

Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can use Font from others source download add it in your project. [check here](https://freefontsfamily.com/times-new-roman-font-free/#google_vignette) for your font.

Add your font files into your project folder. Say Project Folder > assets > fonts > Times New Roman.

Declare the font family with font files with style in your project's pubspec.yaml file as (An example):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.Download your custom fonts

2.Add it in your projects

[image]

3.Declare in your pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: Times
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/times/times.ttf
```

4.Call it your MaterialApp()

```
     MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Times'),
      home: const LandingPage(),
    );
```